# MariaDB error messages with missing debug information

Tags: sql, mariadb

I get MariaDB constraint violation errors with missing debug information. I'm running MariaDB 10.10.2 via Docker. I couldn't find any information about this behavior via Google. Any suggestion what is causing this or how to fix it? It's quite annoying to debug. The error string looks like this:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (., CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES  ())
```

That's all I get.

Comment: Do you have a snippet code or sth. like that? I think you need to delete something first before you can perform your delete operation specified here.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specefic enough. I do know that this error is caused on delete / update because of a constraint. However I don't understand why the error message does not include information about which table, key and columns are causing this as it usually does. This makes it more complicated to find the causing constraint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is indeed not very descriptive. A more detailed explanation about the last foreign key error can be obtained by
executing

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

The `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section of the output should contain more information about the constraint violation.

Comment: Thanks, the status has indeed the full error message including the table, key and references. I'm still curious why it's not included in the error message I get from the exception though.

Comment: I looked through the server code, its worthy of a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org). There appears to be the intent to print it, its just populated with the text of the error message again.